# ¿Cómo puedo aumentar la gravedad de un objeto con el tiempo en unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en unity pero todavía no tengo mucha experiencia, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pase por ejemplo 30 segundos de un contador la velocidad de mi enemigo aumente. Los scripts de los enemigos y del contador ya los tengo pero no consigo hacer que cambie la gravedad.
No se como hacer para que los dos scripts se comuniquen entre si y tampoco se como hacer para aumentar la gravedad.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Script del enemigo

{

```
public float minRotateSpeed = 45f;
public float maxRotateSpeed = 80f;
private float currentSpeedRotation;

public float minGravityScale = 0.1f;
public float maxGravityScale = 0.4f;
private float currenGravityScale;

public float minScale = 0.01f;
public float maxScale = 0.03f;
private float currenScale;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    RandomizeAsteroid();
    Destroy(gameObject, 20f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, currentSpeedRotation * Time.deltaTime));
}

private void RandomizeAsteroid()
{
    currentSpeedRotation = Random.Range(minRotateSpeed, maxRotateSpeed);

    currenGravityScale = Random.Range(minGravityScale, maxGravityScale);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = currenGravityScale;

    currenScale = Random.Range(minScale, maxScale);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(currenScale, currenScale, currenScale);
}
```

}

Script del cronometro

```
{
public static TimeR instanciar;
public Text Crono;
private TimeSpan tiempoCrono;
private bool timerBool;
private float tiempoTrans;


private void Awake()
{
    instanciar = this;
}


private void Start()
{
    Crono.text = "00:00";
    timerBool = false;
}


public void iniciarTiempo()
{
    timerBool = true;
    tiempoTrans = 0f;

    StartCoroutine(ActUpdate());
}

public void FinTiempo()
{
    timerBool = false;
}


private IEnumerator ActUpdate()
{
    while (timerBool)
    {
        tiempoTrans += Time.deltaTime;
        tiempoCrono = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tiempoTrans);
        string tiempoCronoStr = tiempoCrono.ToString("mm':'ss");
        Crono.text = tiempoCronoStr;

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

}